# compose tail and head

Tags: elm

Q: elm 0.15 won't let me to (tail >> head) xs. How to solve this in an elegant way ?

```
module Fibonacci where

import List exposing ((::), head, map2, reverse, tail)

fibonacci : Int -> List Int
fibonacci n =
    let fibonacci' n acc =
        if n <= 2
            then acc
            else fibonacci' (n-1) ((head acc + (tail >> head) acc) :: acc)
    in
        fibonacci' n [1,1] |> reverse
```

Since:

```
head : List a -> Maybe a
tail : List a -> Maybe (List a)
```

I don't know how to convert `Maybe (List a) to be List a`

So, is there any easy way to compose these 2 function without defining a new function ?

Comment: @Mauris People occasionally add [haskell] to questions about Haskell-inspired languages like Elm or PureScript hoping to find a wider audience of people able to help. I have no settled opinion on whether it is acceptable or not.

Comment: While not an answer to the question of "how do I compose `head` and `tail`, if you actually want to know "how do I get the sum of the first 2 numbers in a `List number` in a nice way, when I know there are at least 2 elements in the list?" then `take 2 >> sum` will work for your case. see: https://gist.github.com/robertjlooby/1950525cb9a4745ecc2d

Answer (score 6):

What you want is, technically speaking, *[Kleisli composition](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/Lkey/kleisli) in the Maybe monad*:

```
import List exposing (head, tail)
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)

(>=>) : (a -> Maybe b) -> (b -> Maybe c) -> (a -> Maybe c)
f >=> g = \a -> case f a of Nothing -> Nothing
                            Just b  -> g b

-- or: f >=> g = f >> (\x -> Maybe.andThen x g)

main = show ((tail >=> head) [1,2,3,4,5])
```

Note how the type of `(>=>)` is very similar to that of `(>>)`, but all of the **return types** are wrapped in `Maybe`. You can chain arbitrary `Maybe`-returning functions together this way (like `tail >=> tail >=> tail >=> head`).

You can't type-safely convert `Maybe a` to `a`, as you'd have no option but to crash when given `Nothing`. You *can*, however, flatten a `Maybe (Maybe a)` value down to a `Maybe a`:

```
flattenMaybe : Maybe (Maybe a) -> Maybe a
flattenMaybe mma = 
  case mma of Just (Just a) -> Just a
              _             -> Nothing
```

Comment: "f >=> g = f >> Maybe.andThen g" has error on elm 0.15. Conflict between "Maybe b" and "a -> Maybe b"